# Is there any simple way to restrict all Windows 10 services allow only local subnet with Windows Defender Firewall?

Tags: windows-10, networking, firewall, windows-defender

I have a Windows 10 computer in my home local subnet.
Now I configured Windwos Defender Advanced Firewall security's Remote Desktop rules to allow scope 'Local subnet'
My subnet is behind of my home Internet router, the subnet has some ethernet and Wifi devices.

**Question**

I got the idea, that all services should be restricted similar way to the 'Local subnet'.
Is there any simple way to do that, instead configuring scopes one by one?

After the config I still want to allow all my applications (browser, Kodi, etc) to access to the Internet)